# python function, beautifulsoup scraping

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to turn this into a function

```
#scrape

for parsed_link in soup.findAll('a', {'target':'Map'}):
    links.extend(parsed_link.contents)
```

to return results in a list called "links". It works fine as above but my solution for a function is not working. This is what I have:

```
def scrape():
    parsed_link = soup.findAll('a', {'target':'Map'})
    links.extend(parsed_link.contents)
```

Where am I going wrong? All help appreciated.

for completeness, here is the rest of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Kane\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://www.fieldmycology.net/FRDBI/FRDBIrecord.asp?intGBNum=1511'
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
links = []

for parsed_link in soup.findAll('a', {'target':'Map'}):
    links.extend(parsed_link.contents)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would turn it into a function:

```
def scrape(soup):
    links = []

    for parsed_link in soup.findAll('a', {'target':'Map'}):
        links.append(parsed_link.contents)

    return links

...


soup = ...
links = scrape(soup)
```

The second example didn't have the `for` loop. And you probably want to `append` to the list, not `extend`. This function takes `soup` as a parameter, and then runs the code you provided in the first example, with `links` as the return value

Comment: I'd pass the tag and target as well, just for flexibility.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You could do that, I didn't just for simplicity

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding in a 2nd, more general solution :-)

Comment: No, thank you. I offered my 2c for you to take it or leave it. You decided not to, so your answer will remain that much more "just okay". Cheers.

Comment: thanks for helping, you've taught me something great :D